# Wifi Television

Tags: wireless-networking, tv

Im looking to purchase a Wifi television and would like some recommendations. It would preferably need to be hardwired to the network. The solution will allow laptops to display their desktop image without a dongle or software.

This would be for laptops to display presentations, also keeping the laptop connected to the internet and internal network.

Comment: A wireless vga adapter that does not need drivers and connects to a tv would be another solution. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [DLNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Living_Network_Alliance) devices.